# how to represent floating points in binary?

Tags: binary, floating-point

I have been working on these three lab questions for about 5 hours. I'm stuck on the last question.

> Consider the following floating point number representation which
>   stores a floating point number is 16 bits. You have a sign-bit, a six
>   bit (excess-32) exponent, and a nine bit mantissa.
>
> 3. Explain how the 9-bit mantissa might get you into trouble.

Here is the preceding question. Not sure if it will help in analysis.

> 2. What is the range of exponents it supports?
>
> `000000` to `111111` or 0 to 63 where exponent values less
>   than 32 are negative, and exponent values greater than 32 are
>   positive.

I have a pretty good foundation for floating points and converting between decimals and floating points. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess there is a typo in the second quote, should "32" be considered a positive or negative exponent? If we should go after the first quote, then "32" should be positive, or in fact 2^0 or simply 1. (Not that it answers the question...)

Comment: Good catch, I'm not sure what the right answer is for that. The excess is 32. As I understand it that is the point where it switches from negative to positive, but which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, the ratio mantissa to exponent is a bit off. Even if we assume there is a hidden bit, effectively making this into a 10 bit mantissa (with top bit always set), you can represent + or - 2^31, but in 2^31/2^10 = 2^21 steps (i.e. steps of 2097152).

I'd rather use 11 bits mantissa and 5 bit exponent, making this 2^15/2^11 = 2^4, i.e. steps of 16.

So for me the trouble would be that 9+1 bits is simply too imprecise, compared to the relatively large exponent.

Comment: Had to read this a couple of times to really get it. But once I got it, it is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that a nine-bit mantissa simply provides far too little precision, so that any operation apart from trivial ones, will make the calculation far too inexact to be useful.

I admit this answer is a little bit far-fetched, but apart from this, I can't see a problem with the representation.